# how to stop the result on the current date?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm having prob,when i open the app i can see the latest result,when i swipe left of the uiview i can see the previous result,the problem that i face i wanted to swipe right to come for the latest result again.

the is the code for swipe left

```
-(void)swipeLeft
{


    NSLog(@"Mag Date:%@",magCurDate);
    NSDate *tempDate;

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    tempDate = [formatter dateFromString:magCurDate];

    NSLog(@"temp Date:%@",tempDate);

    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [dateComponents setDay:-1];
    [dateComponents setHour:8];
    NSDate *targetDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:tempDate  options:0];

    NSLog(@"target Date:%@",targetDate);

    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"ddMMYYYY"];
    NSString *sDate = [df stringFromDate:targetDate];

    NSLog(@"sDate Date:%@",sDate);

    [self LoadMagnumResult:sDate];

}
```

this is my swipe right code,but i couldn't stop on the latest result,i want the last swipe to be the latest result.

```
-(void)swipeRight
{


    NSLog(@"Mag Date:%@",magCurDate);
    NSDate *tempDate;

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    tempDate = [formatter dateFromString:magCurDate];

    NSLog(@"temp Date:%@",tempDate);

    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [dateComponents setDay:+1];
    [dateComponents setHour:8];
    NSDate *targetDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:tempDate  options:0];

    NSLog(@"target Date:%@",targetDate);

    NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"ddMMYYYY"];
    NSString *sDate = [df stringFromDate:targetDate];

    NSLog(@"sDate Date:%@",sDate);

    [self LoadMagnumResult:sDate];

}
```

Comment: we have no context within which to understand 'result'.  Potential answerers will need to understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: hi prediv, your code seems to minus 16hours (-1day & +8hours) or plus 32hours (+1day & +8hours). Is your logic correct?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the latest result cannot be in the future.  In other words, the max date for "latest result" is today.  I'm also assuming that a left swipe should increment the information until today is reached.  If you want a left swipe to jump to today, then the code is even easier.  Let me know if that's what you meant.  Since I don't have your application, I just made an internal variable that stored a date called testDate.  I also put a label on screen and called it outputLabel.  You can modify the code to fit your needs.

Finally, I changed the methods to make the right swipe go back in time and the left swipe go forward in time.  A user is already used to thinking of a right swipe as going backwards (back on a web browser, etc).  Remember a right swipe starts on the left and ends on the right.

First, I would build a helper method to turn dates into strings:

```
- (NSString*)stringFromDate:(NSDate*)date
{
    //Helper method to return a string from a date
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yy"];
    return [formatter stringFromDate:date];
}
```

This is my right swipe method.  Notice how I use time intervals to increment dates.  That can save you a few lines of code from your methods.  Unless I'm wrong, it looks like you are trying to increment the date by 24 hours for each swipe.  I also made a constant before these two methods so you don't have to search through your code if you want to change the days to increment per swipe.

```
#define kDaysPerSwipe 1

- (void)swipeRight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)swipeRight
{
    NSLog(@"right swipe received");

    //Number of days to add
    int numberOfDaysToAdd = kDaysPerSwipe;

    //Generate a new date
    NSDate *newDate = [self.testDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:-(60*60*24*numberOfDaysToAdd)];

    //Store the new date
    self.testDate = newDate;

    //Output the new date
    self.outputLabel.text = [self stringFromDate:self.testDate];
}
```

Here is my left swipe method.  Notice how I compare the newDate to today and then only store the EARLIER date of the two before proceeding.

```
- (void)swipeLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)swipeLeft
{
    NSLog(@"left swipe received");

    //Number of days to add
    int numberOfDaysToAdd = kDaysPerSwipe;

    //Generate a new date
    NSDate *newDate = [self.testDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:(60*60*24*numberOfDaysToAdd)];

    NSLog(@"newDate: %@", [self stringFromDate:newDate]);

    //Compare newDate to today.  Return whichever is earlier.
    newDate = [[NSDate date] earlierDate:newDate];

    self.testDate = newDate;

    //Show the output on the screen
    self.outputLabel.text = [self stringFromDate:self.testDate];
}
```

Comment: hi jb_Oh, do u have Skype?so i can chat with u

Comment: hop,it have to stop on the latest result of the day

Comment: I don't understand. You want a forward swipe to stop on the latest result?  Would you have results in the future?  The code I posted will stop on today.